# Change default sort order in Manage Products admin

Tags: admin, sorting

In the admin Manage Products area, I want to set the default sort to newest first (via created_at) so the latest products added to my site are displayed first.

Everything I have tried to fix this doesn't seem to work and the majority of fixes appear to apply to the front end only, whereas I need it strictly for the back end.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Typical! After hours of searching I make a post...only to find the answer 5 minutes later.

Modify the local file `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` and make line 41 read:

```
$this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
```